# how to pre-select a dropdown options which are dynamically generating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I am getting the select dropdown options from the server, and i have stored a value in a variable in javascript. If the options are matching to the value i am having that will be preselected in the select dropdown. Below is my code.

> this is to get the dropdown options from server and append to select dropdown.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/enquiry/user',
         dataSrc: "data",
         dataType : 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(users){
            var mySelect = $('#assigned');
    $.each(users, function(index, options){
      console.log(options._id);
       mySelect.append(
    $('<option></option>').val(options._id).html(options.firstName)
);
        // $('#assigned').append('<option value="'+users._id+'">'+users.firstName+'</option>');
    });
```

> and here i am having a value in a variable`f8 = document.getElementById('assigned');`

If the value in f8 matches to the options, that option should get pre-selected.

> Iam using materialize CSS

Html dropdown
`<select id="assigned">
<option value="">Change Assignee</option>
</select>`

Comment: `mySelect.val('whatever')` to set select value using jquery

Comment: $("#assigned").val(f8); just add dropdown name and in val write variable name

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, @GSB , this line "$("#assigned").val(f8);" should be written after my ajax call? right!

Comment: @Manoj yes after ajax call you need to call

Comment: @GSB I added but its not working

Comment: @Manoj IN the Ajax Success After the finish of Append Each

Comment: @Manoj your variable value you are retrieving in this format right? f8 = document.getElementById('assigned'); if yes so please call your ajax in $(document).ready(function() { 
$.ajax({//coded here});  $("#assigned").val(f8);});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#optionID').prop('selected',true)

//to update material select component per materializecss doc
$('#select').material_select('destroy')
$('#select').material_select()
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kz3aLk88/), though not ajax request, but dynamically generated options

edit:

```
$('#select').append($('<option></option>').val(VALUE).html(HTML))
$('#select').val(SELECTED_VALUE)
$('#select').material_select('destroy')
$('#select').material_select()
```

Comment: i gave id to my options like this,is this the right way "$('<option></option>').val(options.firstName).id(options.firstName).html(options.firstName)"

Comment: it sort of also works, check the updated code... though admittedly, it is behaving a little strangely. edit: working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ayetx8o3/